# Using "like" inside a "case" statement with 2 different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have 2 fields in my table on which i need a case statement.

```
Col1          Col2     Col3
abc.txt       Y        0
def.txt       N        0
bbck.txt      Y        1
```

The `Col3` values are based on the `Col1` and `Col2` values in the following manner.
`Y = 1` and `N = 0`. So all the values in `Col2` that are `Y` shall become `1` in `col3`, and `N`in `Col2` will become `0` in `Col3`, UNLESS the `col1` value ends with `%c.txt`. As you can see since the `abc.txt` ends with `%c.txt` the value in `col3` becomes `0`.

I know this can be done with a `CASE` statement nested maybe to get this done. Does anyone know how to?

here's my code

```
SELECT 
  CASE Col2
    WHEN 'Y' THEN '1'
    WHEN 'N' THEN '0'
  ELSE
(CASE WHEN [Col1] LIKE '%c.txt' THEN '0'
 END)
  END
  AS Col3,
 *
FROM Tabl1
```

Hope  this gives an idea

Comment: This question is very unclear and would suggest posting what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have tried that lot of times. i am logged in, but when i refresh few times, i cant pick answer anymore, even if i've logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN Col2 = 'N'
        OR Col1 LIKE '%c.txt'
          THEN '0'
      WHEN Col2 = 'Y'
          THEN '1'
    END AS Col3
  , * 
FROM Tabl1
```

Comment: The `WHEN Col2 = 'Y' THEN '1'` can be replaced with `ELSE '1'` if `Col2` has only `Y` and `N` values and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for:

```
 SELECT * FROM Tabl1
 cross apply
    (
      select Col3 =
      CASE  
            WHEN Tabl1.Col2 = 'Y' then '1'
            WHEN Tabl1.Col2 = 'Y' then '1'
            WHEN RIGHT(Tabl1.Col1, 6) = 'c.txt' then '0'
            END 
) as Col3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Col2 LIKE '%c.txt' THEN '0'
       ELSE
       CASE 
            WHEN Col2  = 'N'  THEN '0'
            WHEN Col2  = 'Y' THEN '1'
       END
  END AS COL3
FROM Tabl1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your spec is clear enough e.g. is the comma before the word "UNLESS" suposed to incidicate that the following clause applies to *both* the previous clauses?

There seems to be four possible combinations:

```
1) Col1 LIKE '%c.txt'
   AND Col2 = 'Y'

2) Col1 LIKE '%c.txt'
   AND Col2 = 'N'

3) Col1 NOT LIKE '%c.txt'
   AND Col2 = 'Y'

4) Col1 NOT LIKE '%c.txt'
   AND Col2 = 'N'
```

You say

> i need a case statement

Is this true? With SQL, the same thing can always be achieved multiple ways (which is why it is so hard to build a good optimizer :) I think a spec should state **what** is required and not place unreasonable restrictions on **how** to implement it.

The following uses `UNION` rather than case and if you had considered this from the start then maybe your spec would be better ;)

```
WITH Tabl1
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('abc.txt', 'Y'),
                     ('def.txt', 'N'),
                     ('bbck.txt', 'Y'),
                     ('disc.txt', 'N')
             ) AS T (Col1, Col2)
     )
SELECT '0' AS Col3, *
  FROM Tabl1
 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%c.txt'
       AND Col2 = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT '0' AS Col3, *
  FROM Tabl1
 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%c.txt'
       AND Col2 = 'N'
UNION
SELECT '1' AS Col3, *
  FROM Tabl1
 WHERE Col1 NOT LIKE '%c.txt'
       AND Col2 = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT '0' AS Col3, *
  FROM Tabl1
 WHERE Col1 NOT LIKE '%c.txt'
       AND Col2 = 'N';
```

P.S. I coded this to match the accepted answer but I'm not convinced it is correct!